# Devise (3.4.1 2f0002a), undefined method `flash' for ActionDispatch::Request, rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

When I `sign up` or `sign in` using `devise`. I get following error:

```
undefined method `flash' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0xda424ac>
```

This is my first project using `rails 4.2`, all previous projects had atmost `rails 4.1.8` and I never had similar issue.

Error trace path is:

```
.../.rvmruby (2.1.2) bundler/gems/devise-2f0002a449a8/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:18:in `flash'
.../.rvmruby (2.1.2) bundler/gems/devise-2f0002a449a8/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:58:in `redirect'
.../.rvmruby (2.1.2) bundler/gems/devise-2f0002a449a8/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:39:in `respond'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
```

If you need any more information please say, I am stuck with this for some time.

I have seen people having issues using `rails-api` gem, but I am not using `rails-api` gem.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding to  your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

Comment: When I add this, then I can not log in. What ever action I try, I get 401 Unauthorized (action with devise)

Comment: config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options     config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash

Comment: @Thomas This solved the problem for me, but could you explain why? Also, this seemed to happen only on production, not development. Shouldn't ::Flash be included in stock rails?